# Azure BlobClient VS CloudBlobClient

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-blob-storage

I've been learning Azure recently and I see that there are 2 classes for working with blobs: `CloudBlobClient` and `BlobClient`.

`CloudBlobClient` is from`Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;` namespace, while `BlobClient` is from `Azure.Storage.Blobs`namespace.

What is the difference between them?
When would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The package [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs) is latest version for azure blob storage, and [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/) is the older version.

So we suggest that you should always use the `BlobClient` which is from the latest package. But if you have some old project which is using the old package, then in that case, you can use `CloudBlobClient`.

Answer (score 7):

`Azure.Storage.Blobs` is a new version of Nuget package for Azure Blob Storage service. `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` is an older version.

Some classes including `CloudBlobClient` have been renamed in the new version. `CloudBlobClient` is renamed to `BlobServiceClient`.

The following page shows a list of renamed classes and sample code for upgrading to the new version.
https://elcamino.cloud/articles/2020-03-30-azure-storage-blobs-net-sdk-v12-upgrade-guide-and-tips.html

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` is the older SDK version 11, while `Azure.Storage.Blobs` starts from SDK version 12.

A critical difference is that the new SDK does not allow setting of permissions.

However, creating an instance of say `BlobServiceClient` does not require the creation of an intermediate `CloudStorageAccount` object, as the `CloudBlobClient` does. Simply supplying the connection string to the constructor of `BlobServiceClient` is enough to create this object.